# C++ Memory Model - Sequentially Consistent

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, atomic, memory-model

I have a question about C++'s memory order "Sequential Consistent".

Background: After tested the example(shown below) provided by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), which is also served as *Listing 5.4* in Anthony Williams's [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294691)). I found that the `assert` is still not fired after all `memory_order_seq_cst` are replaced with `memory_order_relaxed`, which is contradictory to cppreference's statement

> Any other ordering may trigger the assert because it would be possible for the threads c and d to observe changes to the atomics x and y in opposite order.

and Anthony's statement:

> This constraint doesn’t carry forward to threads that use atomic operations with relaxed memory orderings;

In other words, according to my test(10000+ times), or [online test](https://godbolt.org/z/P511bs97c), there is no much difference between `seq_cst` and `relaxed` orders, that is, if I changed memory order from 'Sequential Consistent' to 'Relaxed', the program yields the same result.

So my **question** is:

> ##### Why the `Relaxed` ordering behaves as the same way as the `Sequential Consistent` ordering in this example?

---

Test:

```bash
# Compile
c++ example.cc

# Check 1000+ times
for i in {1..100000}; do ./a.out; done;
# ...... all succeed, none aborted
```

Code:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
 
std::atomic<bool> x = {false};
std::atomic<bool> y = {false};
std::atomic<int> z = {0};
 
void write_x()
{
    x.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
 
void write_y()
{
    y.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
 
void read_x_then_y()
{
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        ;
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        ++z;
    }
}
 
void read_y_then_x()
{
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))
        ;
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
        ++z;
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread a(write_x);
    std::thread b(write_y);
    std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
    std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join(); d.join();
    assert(z.load() != 0);  // will never happen
}
```

Comment: They are not telling you the assert _will_ trigger. They are telling you it can. (I believe this can be very hard to test on x86 which has "strong" guarantees at the CPU level, above what C++ requires. Not an expert though.)

Comment: "may trigger" is consistent with "does not trigger"

Comment: In standardese, the word "may" essentially means "permitted", which is optional not mandatory.   If something is mandatory, the word "shall" is used or (where that is ambiguous) "must".   The wording "Any other ordering may trigger the assert ..." would have the meaning you expect if the word "may" was changed to "shall" or "must"

Comment: Getting these kind of litmus tests to actually trigger can be tricky.  I've worked on a few.  Some techniques I found helpful: (1) Use a weakly-ordered architecture, such as ARM64. (2) Use `alignas` to get every variable in its own cache line; otherwise accessing one can effectively "lock" another one.  (3) Insert prefetches and cache line flushes at strategic points, to try to ensure that certain loads complete faster or slower than others and thus are likely to get reordered.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! There is likely no online ARM64 compilers, might go for the second choice, but how can I make use of `alignas` to make the trigger possible?

Comment: I meant that I used *all* of those techniques together to get it to trigger.  I don't think it is possible for it to trigger on x86, no matter how you align stuff or prefetch, because LoadLoad reordering does not happen in hardware, and there is a total order on stores.  Unless your compiler does some reordering as they optimize, which would be legal but AFAIK not done by any current compiler.

Comment: The other thing is even on a machine where it can happen, if you only do the test once per run of the program, you'll probably never see it; the tests I've done would trigger maybe once every million iterations, and the overhead of starting threads tends to serialize things.  So you need to write code to run the tests over and over again in a tight loop, resetting everything and getting the threads to resynchronize with each other in between.

Comment: But in general, you want to keep in mind that many aspects of C++ are non-deterministic, especially with regard to threads.  Basically, unless you can prove that it *won't* do some thing, you have to assume that it could, whether or not it actually happens in your tests.  Just because code works a certain way in one test, you should not draw the conclusion that this is how the language promises it will always work.  So unlike with some other languages, experimentation is of limited value in learning about the C++.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the thorough explanations. By yours, and along with a [2017 paper](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/scfix/), I finally realized that C++ memory model is not just complex,  but also too subtle to catch it under current circumstances. Those fields might still be in active research, or be attractive for those strike for the ultimate high performance computation, but definitely not fit in normal individual Cpper's needs. I am the latter one, and I think I should use the conventional pthread-like mutex/locking semantics to gain more performance benefit. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Another thing which may be needed to trigger some allowed behavior is ensuring that the threads are on different physical CPU, as staying on chip may use stronger memory order than when going out of chip -- and that's even more the case if you allow  SMT/Hyperthreading.